# Android app is lagging when trying to use any input

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason I am experiencing massive lag when I try to use the input fields and buttons in my app. The lag is present both in the emulator that comes with Android Studio and my own One Plus Two. I really don't have much code at all so I find this very strange. The app is also using about 150Mb of RAM despite the images used are below 1Mb in total size. The app sometimes even stop responding. I am new to Android development but familiar with programming.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/logoCS"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_with"
        android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@color/signature_gray" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/googleButton"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_with"
        android:src="@drawable/google"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facebookButton"
        android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/emailField"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@color/signature_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/or"
        android:textColor="@color/signature_gray"
        android:id="@+id/orTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/googleButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_below="@id/orTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:textColorHint="@color/signature_gray"
        android:textColor="@color/signature_gray"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailField"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:textColorHint="@color/signature_gray"
        android:textColor="@color/signature_gray"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="forgotPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/sing_in_error"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:id="@+id/errorText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/forgotPasswordText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/forgotPasswordText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/userIconCS"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/userIcon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailField"
        android:background="@drawable/user" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/pwIconCS"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/passwordIcon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordField"
        android:background="@drawable/password" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/not_a_member"
        android:id="@+id/notMemberField"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/orTextView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/register_now"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/registerText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="register"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/notMemberField"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notMemberField"
        android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notMemberField" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:background="@color/signature"
        android:text="@string/sing_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:onClick="signIn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passwordField" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/googleLogoCS"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/googleImage"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/google"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/googleButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/googleButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/facebookLogoCS"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/facebookImage"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/facebookButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/facebookButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button facebookButton;
    private Button googleButton;
    private EditText emailField;
    private EditText passwordField;
    private Button loginButton;
    private TextView registerText;
    private TextView errorText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        facebookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
        googleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
        emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        registerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerText);
        errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);

        registerText.setPaintFlags(registerText.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with android so excuse me, but are you making sure the methods being called are async? (so they don't hold up the ui thread)

Comment: If the code the OP just shared is the only code, I don't see where asyncs appear. What I know is that onDraw could be costly. Can you post more code if you have any?

Comment: Also, you should be at least extending AppCompatActivity in this day and age

Comment: I am not 100% sure about the lag but my guess is the underline thing might be the root

Comment: This was caused by not placing the drawables in their correct folders by dpi.